# Upgrading problem

Tags: permissions, automatic-updates

I am using a CentOs server that managed with Plesk panel. All domains have different users. I have 2 different installation of WordPress. One is installed from FTP and the other one is installed from Plesk.

WP installed from FTP cannot be updated from admin panel of WP. The error is;

> Downloading update from
>   http://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.4.2-no-content.zip…
>
> Unpacking the update…
>
> Could not copy files.
>
> Installation Failed

WP installed from Plesk can be updated successfully from admin panel of WP. So I check the permissions and file ownership and did the same as WP installed from Plesk. But it doesn't fix the issue.

Any suggestion?

PS: I know how to update from FTP.
PS2: I won't disable 'define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by changing file ownership to apache:apache

Comment: This is not a secure fix. If the Apache process owns the files, then that means anybody with access to the apache process can edit your website. Which, on a shared hosting system, would be any user of the hosting system. The files should be owned by the user account who owns the site, not be owned by a process. If you're not willing to disable the direct filesystem access method, then there is no solution to your problem that maintains the security of the site.

Comment: @Otto; You are right but the site is on a dedicated system. I own the server.

Comment: Well, if you have that level of access to the server, then the correct solution would be to use suPHP or an equivalent method to make the PHP process run as the user that owns the files, not to put the files under the incorrect ownership. Alternatively, you could switch from using the direct method to the SFTP based method or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have write access from the ftp user doesn't mean that the user Apache/PHP is running in has write access.

I'd advise you upgrade manually, or check your write permissions and ownership for whichever user Apache is running as on those files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run these commands (Commands are for both Dashboard and ftp)

```
sudo usermod -aG www-data $USER

sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www

sudo chmod -R 774 /var/www
```